# Wobble text effect + gradient text does not work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I'm attempting to make a header that utilizes both a wobbling text effect and a gradient for the text. Here is the code:

Wobble.js (from [here](http://www.mf2fm.com/rv/dhtmlwobble.php))

```
// <![CDATA[
var speed=100; // speed of wobbling, lower is faster
var height=3; // height of wobbling in pixels
var alink=""; // page to link text to (set to ="" for no link)

/****************************
*    Wobbly Text Effect     *
*(c) 2003-6 mf2fm web-design*
*  http://www.mf2fm.com/rv  *
* DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS BOX *
****************************/
var wobtxt, wobble, wobcnt=0;
window.onload=function() { if (document.getElementById) {
  var i, wobli;
  wobble=document.getElementById("wobble");
  wobtxt=wobble.firstChild.nodeValue;
  while (wobble.childNodes.length) wobble.removeChild(wobble.childNodes[0]);
  for (i=0; i<wobtxt.length; i++) {
    wobli=document.createElement("span");
    wobli.setAttribute("id", "wobb"+i);
    wobli.style.position="relative";
    wobli.appendChild(document.createTextNode(wobtxt.charAt(i)));
    if (alink) {
      wobli.style.cursor="pointer";
      wobli.onclick=function() { top.location.href=alink; }
    }
    wobble.appendChild(wobli);
  }
  setInterval("wobbler()", speed);
}}

function wobbler() {
  for (var i=0; i<wobtxt.length; i++) document.getElementById("wobb"+i).style.top=Math.round(height*Math.sin(i+wobcnt))+"px"
  wobcnt++;
}
// ]]>
```

h1 CSS

```
h1{ 
     text-align: center;
     background: linear-gradient(to right, #d1ff00,
                    #a2ff00, #00ffaa, #00ffaa);
     -webkit-background-clip: text;        
     -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
     filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px #0dcc0d);
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    h1:after {
      background: linear-gradient(to right, #d1ff00,
                    #a2ff00, #00ffaa, #00ffaa);
    }
```

The HTML itself:

```
<h1><span id= "wobble">TEXT</span></h1>
```

This works as intended in Firefox. But in Chrome, the text is transparent (it is still there if I highlight it). The text shows up in Chrome if I delete the wobble span, but with it, it becomes invisible.

I've attempted all sorts of combinations for the gradient, background, clipping, etc. with the -webkit- variants and -moz- variants. I've tried with h1:after both present and not present. Still, nothing.

Does anybody know why this occurs?